# Wordpress change the title of pages, posts.. from a plugin

Tags: wordpress

I created a plugin named zero.php to change my titles.
I acticated my plugin in the back office
The problem is nothing works.

I tried this

```
    <?php
/*
Plugin Name: zero
*/


add_filter('wp_title', 'zero_modify_page_title',20);
function zero_modify_page_title($title) {
 return $title .'|Avec le plugin zero';
}
 ?>
```

and this

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: zero
*/


add_filter('pre_get_document_title', 'zero_modify_page_title',20);
function zero_modify_page_title($title) {
 return $title .'|Avec le plugin zero';
}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

add_filter('the_title', 'zero_modify_page_title',20);

function zero_modify_page_title($title, $id) {
 return $title .'|Avec le plugin zero';
}
```

Comment: Great.  Please mark this as answered so others can see the solution if needed.  Thanks.